# Issue on Accessing To Ajax Enqeued File to Pass to URL for Ajax Call

Tags: theme-development, ajax

I am trying to access to a custom php file in WP theme directory to pass to an jQuery Ajax call. I have added foloowing code In `function.php` to register the script and PHP file

```
function add_ajax() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'addproducts', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/addproducts.js', array('jquery'),'',true );
 wp_localize_script('addproducts', 'ajax_custom', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('session.php')));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_ajax' );
```

now in my JavaScript file I am trying to pass url like `url: ajaxurl`

```
var request = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: ajaxurl,
```

but I am getting the `ajaxurl is not defined` error

> addproducts.js?ver=4.9.6:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxurl is not
>   defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement. (addproducts.js?ver=4.9.6:6)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=4.9.6:3)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js?ver=4.9.6:3)

can you please let me know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And it had no chance to work correctly.

When you use `wp_localize_script` like that:

```
wp_localize_script( $handle, $name, $data );
```

then the object called `name` is defined and `data` is it's content. As you can see in [this example from Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script#Example).

So you can't use `ajaxurl` in your JS file, because there is no such variable defined anywhere in your code.

The correct way is:

```
var request = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: ajax_custom.ajaxurl,
```

Comment: Thanks alots Krzysiek, this is working now but I have another problem! how come the URl is landing in `wp-admin` folder like `http://localhost/WP/wp-admin/session.php` instead of the theme directory?

Comment: @Behseini because that’s what admin_url function is for... And you should send it to admin-ajax.php and no to session.php

Comment: @Behseini I think you should read this article before trying to code anything more: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins